# Link / share comment

Tags: discussion, comments, hyperlinks, sharing

How can I share / link a comment, just like I can do with question or answer?

If someone puts a new comment to my stuff and I click reminder about this in the list, I'm getting a direct link to that comment ([example](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/81178/should-i-accept-2-5-year-old-samsung-galaxy-replacement-battery?noredirect=1#comment103838_81178)). But, how can I do the same with any other comment, that I want to share with anyone? I don't see any link / button for this, nor I can't read particular comment's ID.

Comment: The link is available on the timestamp which is displayed after the actual comment and next to the user link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link is available on the timestamp which is displayed after the actual comment and next to the user link.

> [image]

So link to my comment above is:

```
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238661/link-share-comment/238662#comment782142_238661
```

Comment: Thank you! Waiting for time span to accept your answer. However, a clear meaning of purpose of date (instead of timestamp) in tooltip would be very helpful in this case.

Comment: @trejder agreed but the current implementation is killing two birds with one stone. A full timestamp is also needed often.