# Change tooltip under date / share comment link

Tags: feature-request, comments, tooltips

Can we have tooltip under date / share comment link changed from useless (as I think) timestamp to clear meaning of its function (i.e., "Share this comment")?

I've been using Stack Exchange for over a year and I [wasn't aware that the function to share comments existed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238661/189165), nor can I find any reasonable arguments for what use is there to have the timestamp displayed in the tooltip.

*Per comments, I see that timestamp is useful. This leads us to a question: Why we can't have both? For example: `Posted on 2014-08-27 14:20Z. Use this link to share this comment`?*

Comment: When in doubt ... hover! :)

Comment: The timestamps can be useful, considering the time is approximated in clear text. Tomorrow, your question and this comment will both be shown as "one day ago" and more differentiation may be useful.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. See my edited question.

Comment: Better leave the tooltip as is, short and simple. If the team will decide to "promote" the fact we can share comments, better do it via an icon that will appear on hover and act as the "share" link for posts.

Comment: A timestamp next to *something* that links to this *something* is widely used, give it a try on some other websites you use.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a User Experience / Design decision that Stack Exchange has taken and is followed on a couple of places. For example, in addition to link of a comment, post edit timestamp is a link to the post revision history.

Updating the tooltip text could be a good-to-have change but I don't see much value in it. Not doing it may keep the link hidden and if the user is really curious to find it out then spending some time on SE search would be good exercise :)